# Getting the value inside a textbox ng-model using javascript .value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently confuse in trying to obtain the value inside a text box using jquery `.value`

```
<input class="input referral-code" disabled="true" ng-model="account.referral_code_string" id="input-refcode">
```

I tried using `document.getElementById('input-refcode').value` to try to obtain the value but it comes out as empty on my console.

But if I tried binding it onto a `on-click` event, it manages to obtain the value stored inside the `ng-model`

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(){
   console.log(document.getElementbyId('input-refcode'))
});
```

As you can see there is a value inside the text box itself. But when you tried inspecting it, this is what came out.

```
<input class="input referral-code" disabled="true" ng-model="account.referral_code_string" id="input-refcode">
```

If you look at there is no `value` inside the `input textbox`. I'm not sure if it has something to do with `angular.js`

[image]

Comment: `getElementById` <- capital "B"

Comment: When does your jQuery code execute? Does the element exist? Does it have text in it?

Comment: When does your jQuery code execute? `After rendering the document` Does the element exist? `Yes` Does it have text in it? `Yes`

Comment: You'll need to prove it. If the element exists, with that `id` and containing text, then `document.getElementById('input-refcode').value` should return that text

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `scope` object using element

```
var scope =  angular.element(document.getElementById('input-refcode')).scope();
var desiredValue = scope.account.referral_code_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

inject $timeout service in controller

```
$timeout(function(){
 console.log(document.getElementById('input-refcode')); },200);
```

Note: Use capital B in getElementById not getElementbyId.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller('TodoListController', function($scope){

        $scope.$watch('referral_code_string'), function(){ console.log($scope.referral_code_string)};
    
     console.log(document.getElementById('input-refcode').value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
<input class="input referral-code" disabled="true"  ng-model="referral_code_string"  ng-init="referral_code_string = 'abc'" id="input-refcode" value="abc">
</div>
```